# <li> getting stacked in IE7

Tags: html

I am having issue in displaying li horizontally. I read thru the forums and tried couple suggested solutions, but didn't help. I am attaching my code here, could someone please help me get this navigation dispaly horizontally (and compatible across browser).

Here is my code:

> nav.PgHdrMenu{
>       height: 35px;
>       float: right;
>       a{
>       text-decoration: none;
>       letter-spacing: -1px;
>       color: @darkGrey;
>       padding-right: 6px;"

```
&:hover{
  color: @mainColor;
    }
 }

 ul{
padding-top:10px;
width:100%;
float:right;

li{
   list-style-type: none;
   float: right;
   margin-left: 5px;
   display: block; 

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 7px;
  border-right: 1px solid #1686a2;
  background: #1686a2;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1686a2), to(@darkGrey)); 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1686a2,  @darkGrey);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1686a2', endColorstr='@darkGrey', GradientType=0);

-moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;


     &:hover{
   background: #1686a2;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@darkGrey), to(#1686a2)); 
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @darkGrey, #1686a2);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@darkGrey', endColorstr='#1686a2', GradientType=0);
    color:@lightGrey;
    }
}

     &:last-child > a{// get rid of last right-margin
 border: none;
        }
}
 }
```

HTML tag:

```
<nav class=PgContentMenu >
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="product.html">Products</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did forget to "close" your CSS definitions with `}`.

For example:

```
ul{
padding-top:10px;
width:100%;
float:right;
```

Is not valid because you didn't close the `{` you open to define the style of ul element. Change to:

```
ul
{
    padding-top:10px;
    width:100%;
    float:right;
}
```

Check all your definitions, you did forget to close most of them. I hope I can give you a small suggestion: we all forget to close an open curly bracket (even without deep nesting), that's why a good indentation will help you a lot to avoid these errors. Moreover if you keep the open bracket on one line alone (like in my second example) you'll see the *block* in a more clear way. It's just coding style but it may save a lot of time and it'll make your *code* more clear (this is 90% personal taste).

Comment: It doesn't look like vanilla CSS, but rather SCSS or a similar metalanguage. Therefore, this is perfectly valid, as nested styles are simply inserted into eachother, and the styles are closed at the end.

Comment: @Nix maybe you're right, I didn't even read whole CSS. Then, if my eyes didn't cheat me, there is one extra closed bracket...anyway I reenforce my _tip_ to use proper indentation...